# Solve the following Problem Please

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok. I'm going crazy here trying to solve the following. I'm looking for a smart person to solve it for me because my brain is a bit slow today.

A guy borrowed $\$500$ from his mother + $\$500$ from his father = $\$1000$ to buy his shoes which costs $\$970$. The change which he got from that was $\$30$. He gave back $\$10$ to his father, $\$10$ to his mother and kept the remainder which was $\$10$ as well.

So technically, Mum  gave $\$490$ + Dad gave $\$490$ + He's still got $\$10 =\$990$....

Problem: $\$10$ short......Where on earth did the $\$10$ go?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Some of your formatting is messed up, would help to fix it. Also, your title could use improving. Regards

Comment: We use dollar signs to start/stop $\LaTeX$ formatting, so if you want real dollar signs you need ot escape them with a backslash like this:  \\$

Comment: [Missing dollar riddle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_dollar_riddle).

Comment: Mom gave \$490, Dad gave \$490. You got \$10 and the store got \$970. \$490 + \$490 = \$10 + \$970.

Comment: Please do not reedit to make the question unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assets: $10 in species + $970 in trade (namely a pair of shoes) = $980
Liabilities: $490 (Mom) and $490 (Dad) = $980.
```

As the Assets = the Liabilities, there is no missing money; just some funny accounting.